# Magento: SQL Query for finding products without specific subcatagories

Tags: mysql, sql, magento

Hi I'm hoping someone can help me with SQL, my website runs Magento and there is a large number of products that don't belong to any sub categories and unfortunately magento does not have a way of displaying the products without categories in admin.

I found this query that displays products with no catagory at all:

```
SELECT e.entity_id, e.sku FROM catalog_product_entity AS e LEFT JOIN catalog_category_product AS l ON l.product_id = e.entity_id WHERE l.category_id IS NULL
```

But is there a way of displaying products not in specific sub-catagories? Like under the catagory "Tables" but not in the sub-catagory "Wooden".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You can use the same SQL query with a little fix.

```
SELECT e.entity_id, e.sku FROM catalog_product_entity AS e LEFT JOIN catalog_category_product AS l ON l.product_id = e.entity_id WHERE l.category_id IN(1,2) AND l.category_id NOT IN(3,4)
```

And You can also use this:

```
     $productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                                ->getCollection()
                                ->joinField(
                                    'category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 
                                    'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left'
                                )
                                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                                ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => array(1,2)))
                                ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('nin' => array(3,4)))
                                ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc');
```